# problems in instagram_graph_user_profile verification

Tags: facebook-graph-api, instagram-api, instagram-graph-api

We are trying to get the instagram_graph_user_profile verification, but we are receiving this error message from meta:

[print of the error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TORNm.png)

We have already sent the information they asked for (the video and instructions to access), but they keep indicating we need to send this information in another place, but we can't find another proper place for it, besides this one: [print](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pLyal.png)

Does anyone know where else we should send this information?

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issues while trying to get them to approve it. You have to make it reeeeally clear to them how to use it, how you're using it. like, as you'd explain it to a 5 year old (no kidding, they're that hard to deal with). I can send you a link to the video that I uploaded to them. Additionally: remember that it should be in english (I noticed you're screenshot is in brazilian portuguese, so I though I should point that out). A colleague of mine, who also speaks portuguese (as do I) tried sending it in portuguese and they straight up ignored it.